# AzureOperationError in 'acquire_token' while using Azure::Arm for creation of resource group or virtual machine

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-resource-manager

The following error i face in authentication objects while creating resource group or a new virtual machine with azure-ruby-sdk. Even though i used the same authentication procedure with reference to GITHUB - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/tree/db80afe9220e0e72348ff152069ea2e33a455169/resource_management/azure_mgmt_compute . using proper tenantid, clientid , and client.

Comment: Can you share the details of the error you're getting?

Comment: The error was as follows:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.8/gems/ms_rest_azure-0.1.2/lib/ms_rest_azure/credentials/application_token_provider.rb:108:in `acquire_token': Couldn't login to Azure, please verify your tenant id, client id and client secret (MsRestAzure::AzureOperationError)

Comment: Does it require that the application should be web app? or native client application  will also be okk